# Hover effect is not working inside th tag

Tags: jquery, css, model-view-controller

I am working on a tooltip functionality where i hover on an icon and display data based on its attribute in meesagebox. Below code is used for mouseenter event.

```
 <span class='csTip fa fa-info-circle' csTipTerm='Agreed Bid' ></span>
```

If i put it independtely it works but when i put it inside any TH in table tag its hover event is not working. Below is code after putting in th.

```
<th>Agreed Bid  <span class='csTip fa fa-info-circle' csTipTerm='Agreed Bid' ></span> </th>
```

Script

```
$(".csTip").mouseenter(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var term = element.attr("csTipTerm");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/help/gettipdetails",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            tipTerm: term
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var offsets = element.offset();
            var posTop = offsets.top;
            var posLeft = offsets.left;
            HelpBox(result.TipID, result.TipTitle, result.HelpDescriptionHTML, { left: posLeft, top: posTop - 200 });
        }
    });
});
```

Can somebody please guide on this?

Comment: where is the hover code?

Comment: show us the JS..? particularly the selector that you used for it..?

Comment: I have updated hover code.Please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
$("table th .csTip").mouseenter(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var term = element.attr("csTipTerm");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/help/gettipdetails",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            tipTerm: term
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var offsets = element.offset();
            var posTop = offsets.top;
            var posLeft = offsets.left;
            HelpBox(result.TipID, result.TipTitle, result.HelpDescriptionHTML, { left: posLeft, top: posTop - 200 });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/B35ED/)

Try this:

```
$( "#outer" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $( ".csTip" ).append( "<div>Handler for .mouseenter() called.</div>" );
});
```